# Force OkHttp3 to pass full URI (including path) to ProxySelector

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I'm working on an application that needs to switch proxies based on URI path for rate limiting purposes. Different api paths have different call weights. We're using a ProxySelector and passing it to `OkHttpClient` instance via builder. The problem is, when `OkHttpClient` calls `ProxySelector#select(URI)`, the URI contains no path, only host.

```java
    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
        final String path = uri.getPath();
        final Proxy proxy = //proxy selection code based on URI path
        return List.of(proxy);
    }
```

For example, if full URI is `https://example.com/some/path`, when calling `uri.getPath()` in the above example it returns only `/`. It looks like OkHttpClient strips the path internally before passing it to `ProxySelector#select(URI)`.

Is it possible to configure/force `OkHttpClient` to pass a full request URI - including path - when calling `ProxySelector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without an enhancement to OkHttp.  There are generally two issues here.

1) OkHttp is not using the original URL, instead rebuilding it in Address

```
this.url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme(sslSocketFactory != null ? "https" : "http")
    .host(uriHost)
    .port(uriPort)
    .build();
```

2) Even if we were not doing this here, OkHttp follows connection coalescing rules (like Firefox, Chrome, Safari), particularly for enabling efficient multiplexing over HTTP/2.  So this would mean that even if the original request used it, a second request to a different path would reuse the existing connection.

There is an open issue for client side load balancing, so maybe explain your requirements there https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4530

With the existing code your best bet is to have two distinct clients and switch between them externally.  You should be able to use a Retrofit CallFactory to make this track switch.

Comment: Thanks, would creating a sub-client for each proxy also work or would I need to make them completely distinct? Right now we have a shared client with some predefined configuration and create sub-clients with more specific options off of that.

Comment: Creating a sub-client with different proxy settings would allow it to reuse the Dispatcher and ConnectionPool.  Share resources but it will still do the right thing.